# After a UK visitor visa is refused, does it mean you can never go to the UK?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, tunisian-citizens

If someone was refused a UK visitor visa, does that mean they cannot visit the UK at all? If so, for how long?

Comment: If you are asking whether, after a refusal, you have to wait before re-applying, you don't. You can re-apply immediately, BUT make sure you look at the reasons for the refusal, fix them, or wait until things change (job, money, home ties, etc.) that put you in a better position to be granted a visa.